# WS Federation (single sign on) module - redirect issue when using SSL offloading

Tags: single-sign-on, ws-federation

We have a site that we are trying to configure as a client in a SSO scenario, using WS Federation and SAML.

Our site sits behind a load balancer that is doing SSL offloading - the connection to the balancer is under https, but decrypted and forwarded (internally) to the actual site under http and port 81.

Somewhere the WS federation module is attempting to redirect us, but is building up the URL based on the port and incoming protocol to the website:

We request:

https://www.contoso.com/application

and are getting redirected to:

**http**://www.contoso.com:81/Application

Which doesn't work as the load balancer (correctly) won't respond on this port.

And it seems to be related to the casing of the virtual directory.  Browsing to

https://www.contoso.com/Application

seems to work without issue.

(Note for completeness, attempting to browse to http://www.contoso.com/Application with no port will correctly redirect us to the SSL secured URL).

---

I am trying to find out:

a) Where this redirect is happening in the pipeline and
b) How to configure it to use the correct external address.

If anybody is able to point me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it.

---

*EDIT 14:19:* Seems to be either the WsFederationAuthenticationModule or the SessionAuthenticationModule.  These do a case sensitive comparison of the incoming url to what it expects and redirects otherwise:

https://brockallen.com/2013/02/08/beware-wif-session-authentication-module-sam-redirects-and-webapi-services-in-the-same-application/

So that seems to be happening, its a matter now of trying to get the site to behave nicely and redirect to the correct *external* url.

---

The following seems to be related and ultimately points to the culprit in the default CookieHandler:

[Windows Identity Foundation and Port Forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799829/windows-identity-foundation-and-port-forwarding)

Looking at that code decompiled in VS, it compares HttpContext.Current.Request.Url against the targetUrl and will redirect to the expected 'cased' version otherwise (in our case including the errant port number).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that explicitly setting the path attribute of the cookie fixes this issue.  Either an empty string or the virtual directory name seems to work:

```
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" name="ContosoAuth"  path="/Application/"/>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://adfsSite" realm="https://www.contoso.com/Application/" reply="https://www.contoso.com/Application/Home" requireHttps="true"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
```